# Invert case in Sublime Text 2

Tags: windows, sublime-text-2

If I have Caps Lock on by accident and type "lIKE THIS", is there a keyboard shortcut to transform it into "Like this"?

I'm familiar with Ctrl+KL to lowercase a selection, but I"m looking to toggle the case of each selected character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find a built in, I wanted to do try out writing a plugin with something more than a Hello World so here it is.

Under `Tools -> New Plugin...` you can create an empty file and paste this in. (Note that python is somewhat particular about white space so if you have any issues make sure the spacing is as I have it below).

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CaseswapCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        region = self.view.sel()[0]
        str = self.view.substr(region)
        ans = ''.join([char.lower() if char.isupper() else char.upper() for char in str ])
        self.view.replace(edit, region, ans)
```

Then edit your key bindings and include something like this.

`{ "keys": ["control+shift+m"], "command": "caseswap" }`

I've only tested this in MacOSX.

Answer (score 3):

Sublime Text 2 has this functionality built in.

> Go to **Edit -> Convert Case -> Swap Case**

You can add a keybinding by opening your user keybindings **Preferences -> Key Bindings - User** and input your desired keybinding like the one above

> { "keys": ["control+shift+m"], "command": "swap_case" }